# Use of "だと" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions

I came across this sentence and I'm not sure about the use of "だと" and after searching for it I'm more confused.

The sentence: 彼はあのビールは好きだと見えたけど、半分しか飲んでなかった

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 彼はあのビールは好きだと見えたけど、半分しか飲んでなかった
>
> It looked like he likes that beer but he only drank half of it.

だと here is the declarative だ you probably know well plus the quotative と which goes with the verb 見えた. Xと見える means "to look like X."